# google cloud Batch prediction only supports Tensorflow.FRAMEWORK_CUSTOM_CLASS

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-ml, gcutil

I am trying to do some image batch predictions on a custom model prediction routine. I have followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/custom-prediction-routines) tutorial for creating the routine wrapper. I have deployed my model as a tar.gz on google cloud ai platform, created a version and so on. Now when I try to launch a batch prediction from command line using this command:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit prediction $JOB_NAME --model $MODEL_NAME \
    --input-paths $INPUT_PATHS \
    --output-path $OUTPUT_PATH \
    --region $REGION \
    --data-format $DATA_FORMAT
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ai-platform.jobs.submit.prediction) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Field: prediction_input.framework Error: Batch prediction only supports Tensorflow.FRAMEWORK_CUSTOM_CLASS
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: Batch prediction only supports Tensorflow.FRAMEWORK_CUSTOM_CLASS
    field: prediction_input.framework
```

The input is in JSON format and I think it is structured in the right way, because in the bucket, on the console, under type it says `{"instances": [{"image_bytes": {"b64": "image/jpeg"}}]}`, and if I click on the JSON it show straight the image that it contains. Pretty cool! 
But I don't understand the error.

Comment: please any help?

Comment: What framework and version are you using does it works locally ?

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer on this too. I am using `RUNTIME_VERSION=1.13 PYTHON_VERSION=3.5 FRAMEWORK=TENSORFLOW`. I will try if it works locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom prediction is currently not supported on batch prediction. It's only supported for online prediction. The error message is supposed to just read: "Batch prediction only supports Tensorflow."